# SOAP UI: how to use property in xpath match assertion

Tags: xpath, xquery, soapui

i am testing a WS that adds events for an user. the last event added has an userEventId incremented, so i don't know in advance its value. to recover it, i use a Property Transfer.

Now, i would like to use an xquery match assertion to test my value. But i don't know how to use my property in the equery expression.

this matches:

```
//events[last()]/userEventId = <userEventId>12</userEventId>
```

returns:

```
<xml-fragment>true</xml-fragment>
```

but this not:

```
//events[last()]/userEventId = <userEventId>${UserEventId}</userEventId>
```

returns:

```
<xml-fragment>false</xml-fragment>
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: the Constains assertions, with ${UserEventId}, matches, so my property is well defined.

Comment: It will only match if it is inside the *last* `<events>` object in the document.

Comment: it is the last one: last userEventId created is 12, and currently ${UserEventId} = 12.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
//events[last()]/userEventId = <userEventId>${#TestCase#UserEventId}</userEventId>
```

`${UserEventId}` by itself will not expand to anything in SoapUI.

Comment: i tried using this: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html#3-1-writing-to-a-temporary-property, and got something like that: //events[last()]/userEventId = <userEventId>${#subscribe_one_event_TestCase#user_event_id}</userEventId>. Still not matching... can you explains the steps and the syntax please?

Comment: The relevant part of the documentation is here: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

works using XPath Match assertion:

```
matches(//events[last()]/userEventId, '${#subscribe_one_event_TestCase#user_event_id}')
```

returns true.

Comment: false positive result